# how to change git config in docker

Tags: git, docker, githooks, git-config

After cloning my git repo, I'm trying to change hook path in the docker container and here's my simple Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git

RUN git config core.hooksPath .husky
RUN git config --list
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

While building, `git config --list` prints out the changed hookPath. But after the build is done, `git config --list` shows no change when I run the command manually in the container.

Can you explain why this happens and is there no way to change git config in the container?

Comment: how are you running the command in the container?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this: an image usually contains an immutable copy of the application code, which means the code wouldn't change, which means there's nothing to `git commit` inside the container, which means the hooks would never trigger.  Do you need to set this up in your non-Docker development environment?

Answer (score -1):

My experience differs and I repro your expected behavior:

```
FROM docker.io/node:lts-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git

COPY . .

RUN git config core.hooksPath .husky
RUN git config --list
```

Then:

```sh
docker build \
--tag=70172374 \
--file=./Dockerfile \
.
```

Yields:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 1/6
Step 2/6
Step 3/6
Step 4/6 : RUN git config core.hooksPath .husky
Step 5/6 : RUN git config --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.hookspath=.husky
Successfully built c7e7f16f6698n.com 443
Successfully tagged 70172374:latest
```

Then:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
70172374:latest \
  ash -c "git config --list"
```

Yields:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.hookspath=.husky
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just realized that I mapped the volumes like `.:/app` in the docker-compose file and it over-writes the local git config file.